# How to read integers or multiple variables pressing enter after each value but stay in one line?

Tags: c#

I want to write a Program which reads the user inputs in the same line. Such as

if we write

```
int x, y, z; 
x = Console.ReadLine();
y = Console.ReadLine();
z = Console.ReadLine();
```

when the user inputs the value of `x` and then press enter it creats a new line to read the value for `y`. Same happens when it's time for z.  But I want it to do like this :
When the user inputs a value for `x` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then it remains in the same line for reading another input which is the value for `y` and then in the same line for reading `z`

eg:
If user inputs 4 for x,  5 for y and  6 for z

```
THE CODE OUTPUT SHOWS LIKE THIS FOR 3 DIFFERENT INTEGERS:
4
5
6

BUT I WANT IT TO BE LIKE THIS:
4  5  6
```

Note that I can easily read multiple values when <kbd>Enter</kbd> pressed once on the line as there plenty existing answers like [Read numbers from the console given in a single line, separated by a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070113/read-numbers-from-the-console-given-in-a-single-line-separated-by-a-space) basically all doing `String.Split`, but it is different from what I want.

Comment: ReadLine returns a string, you can split it and parse it into integers.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-5.0#System_Console_ReadKey_System_Boolean_ - pass in `true`.

Comment: @mjwills thanks for pointing that out. Half answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499132/c-sharp-console-how-to-readline-without-a-new-line-or-undo-a-n-or-a-vert

Comment: First of all, `int x = Console.ReadLine();` will not work. Second, what's the point? Just enter all 3 numbers then press enter?